# OpenMP uses a suprisingly high number of cores

Tags: c++, openmp

I am trying to parallelize a for loop.
Roughly:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
#pragma omp for
    for(int i=0;i<count;++i){
        some_heavy_function_call()
    }
}
```

For debugging and testing `count=2`is used. `some_heay_function_call()` has 
no further parallelism.

I would expect the number of cores used to be 2.
But the OS (Ubuntu) says the the programm uses 8 threads (maximum on my system).

The function is called 2 times, the problem seems not be that I did the loop wrong.

Is my assumption wrong that maximal 2 threads should be used?
If not what might be going on ?

Update:
I was unclear. I do not wonder that 8 threads are spawned. I wonder that all have near 100% load. Sorry.

Update 2:
If I debug with gdb and switch through the threads, I find in 2 threads the function call and in the others:

```
(gdb) #1  0x00007ffff6267e22 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1
(gdb) #2  0x00007ffff6b176da in start_thread (arg=0x7ffff2fc0700) at pthread_create.c:456
456 pthread_create.c: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden.
(gdb) #3  0x00007ffff5d7bd7f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:105
105 ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden.
```

Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden means File or Directory not found.

Comment: Is `count` compile time constant or computed (and not *visible* to the compiler)? OMP may start more threads then actually needed, so that they are available for future calls (and not delaying them).

Comment: Default is typically max no of threads .  If you don't care to specify, use an openmp which supports omp_places=cores.

Comment: Derbug your app and see what the threads are actually doing. Maybe there are some other things going on.

Answer (score 0):

OpenMP will generally use as many threads as there are cores. Set the number yourself if you have a better idea.

```
{
    omp_set_num_threads(2);
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0;i<count;++i){
        some_heavy_function_call();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also tune the number of threads using `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable, which will make the program more flexible (can change from one execution to another).